# Appending empty dataframe with for loop over CSV files

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am dealing with time series data saved in CSV files in a directory. Each CSV file is a day's worth of random data and the file is named accordingly to the month & day of the data it contains.

For SO purposes we can generate some random data:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
from numpy.random import randint
import os

np.random.seed(10)  # added for reproductibility                                                                                                                                                                 

rng = pd.date_range('10/9/2018 00:00', periods=1000, freq='1H')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Random_Number':randint(1, 100, 1000)}, index=rng)
```

With a folder named `csv` in the root directory, create some CSV files representing each day:

```
# create csv's
for date in set(df.index.date):  

    # filter dataframe    
    filtered_df = df.loc[df.index.date == date].copy()

    # save it
    filename = date.strftime('%m_%d')  # filename represented as 'month_day'
    filtered_df.to_csv(f"./csv/{filename}.csv")
```

Question, how do I create an empty pandas df and a program that can loop over all CSV files and append dataset min, max, median summary statistics? (Code below doesnt work)

```
path = './csv/'
filelist = os.listdir(path) 

frame = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date','max', 'min', 'median'])
for file in filelist:
    df2 = pd.read_csv(path+file)
    date_name = date.strftime('%m_%d')
    df2['Date'] = date_name

    frame.append({'Date': date_name, 'max': df2['Random_Number'].max(), 'min': df2['Random_Number'].min(), 'median': df2['Random_Number'].median()})
```

Comment: "Code below doesnt work" is ambiguous.  what error it gives? Giving unexpected result? Please post your expected output.

Comment: Sorry, the error is `TypeError: Can only append a Series if ignore_index=True or if the Series has a name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `concat()` and create an empty DataFrame object before the for loop.

```
path = './csv/'
filelist = os.listdir(path) 

frame = pd.DataFrame() # don't supply anything
for file in filelist:
    df2 = pd.read_csv(path+file)
    date_name = date.strftime('%m_%d')
    df2['Date'] = date_name

    frame = pd.concat([frame, pd.DataFrame({'Date': [date_name], 'max': [df2['Random_Number'].max()], 'min': [df2['Random_Number'].min()], 'median': [df2['Random_Number'].median()]})])
```

However this approach isn't very efficient. A better approach would be to create a dict and then a dataframe at the end

```
frame_dict = {'date': [], 'max': [], 'min': [], 'median': []}
for file in filelist:
    df2 = pd.read_csv(path+file)
    date_name = date.strftime('%m_%d')
    df2['Date'] = date_name

    frame_dict['date'].append(date_name)
    frame_dict['min'].append(df2['Random_Number'].min())
    frame_dict['max'].append(df2['Random_Number'].max())
    frame_dict['median'].append(df2['Random_Number'].median())

frame = pd.DataFrame(frame_dict)
```

Comment: Would you know how I can get around `ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index`?

Comment: It’s better to concat once at the end, instead of doing so for each iteration.